# Table content not resized on mobile

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, font-size

I'm working on making my website responsive using a method similar to [stackLayout](http://www.stacklayout.com/).  The page works well on desktop and adjusts appropriately with varying widths; however, on mobile, all the text contained in tables does not resize, and appears significantly smaller than all other text.  The only style declaration being directly applied to the table is `width: 100%`, and even with direct declarations of font-size, the text does not appear to respond.  This issue prevails no matter the size/type of unit applied to the text.  I'm truly baffled.. and curious whether this is a CSS problem or a result of how the table is being resized.  Any insight would be much appreciated

CSS:

```css
*, table td {
    font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1rem, 1.1em;
}
```

**NOTE**:
It's most evident on devices that are not iPhones

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kaydeee/7tgw9/2/

Comment: What browser are you developing/testing in?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kaydeee/7tgw9/2/embedded/result/   if viewed on mobile, this better reflects the issue.  I'm working in chrome/IE on my desktop and testing mobile on chrome, safari, and the default android browser

Answer (score 0):

Separate your font size property as

```
table td {
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1rem; 
  font-size: 1.1em;
}
```

this might work